# CoreData: Accessing an object used to mark sections in an NSFetchedResultsController

Tags: ios, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller, sections

I have an NSFetchResultsController which returns ManagedObjects arranged by sections.
The sections are the NSString `name` of the `Category` objects which my `Feed` objects share in common:

Now, in some situations I want to obtain the `Category` itself from the section:

```
  NSString *sortKey = @"category.name";
  NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Feed"];
  NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptorCategory = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:sortKey ascending:asc];
```

At this moment, I do this:

```
    Category *cat = ((Feed *)[[[self.fetchedResultsController sections][section] objects] objectAtIndex:0]).category;
```

Which is IMHO quite ugly. Especially as it forbids me to have empty sections which however might happen if I create new sections into which I want to move existing `Feed`s to.

So my question is : how do I access the `Category` object which defines the sections in my `Feed` list?

Also, how could I efficiently gather a list of all the sections in an NSSet?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: For efficient gathering of all the sections in an NSSet, you could consider using KVC Collection Operators: http://nshipster.com/kvc-collection-operators/

Answer (score 1):

Your method to retrieve the section object is OK, you should just include sanity checks.

```
NSArray *feeds = [self.fetchedResultsController.sections[section] objects];
Feed *aFeed = [feeds anyObject];
return aFeed ? aFeed.category : nil;
```

A list of all sections as a `NSSet`:

```
[NSSet setWithArray:self.fetchedResultsController.sections];
```

If you want to use the category entity extensively in your section headers, maybe it is better to change your setup: fetch the Categories rather than the feeds, and change the table view datasource methods to reflect this setup, e.g.

```
// number of rows for section
Category *category = self.fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects[section];
return category.feeds.count;
```

You will need to introduce a sorting criterion to change the `feeds` set into an array for the rows of a section.